# Plane waves in linearized gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-waves

Following Wald's book, I must show that from linearized, source-free, Einstein equations,
$$
\Box \gamma_{ab}=0,
$$
already assuming the gauge, 
$$
\partial^a \gamma_{ab}=0
$$
and searching for plane waves solutions as
$$
\gamma_{ab} = H_{ab}e^{ik_\mu x^\mu},
$$
with $H_{ab}$ a constant tensor, I must get that
$$
k_\mu k^\mu=0.
$$

Here are my steps:

\begin{align}
g^{\alpha \beta} \partial_\alpha \partial_\beta (H_{ab} e^{ik_\mu x^\mu})&=g^{\alpha \beta} H_{ab} [\partial_\alpha (ik_\lambda e^{ik_\mu x^\mu} \partial_\beta x^\lambda)]\\
&=ik_\lambda H_{ab} g^{\alpha \beta} [e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}\partial_\alpha \partial_\beta x^\lambda + ik_\mu e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}(\partial_\alpha x^\mu) (\partial_\beta x^\lambda)]\\
&=iH_{ab}(k_\lambda \Box x^\lambda + ik_\lambda k_\mu (\partial_\alpha x^\mu) (\partial_\beta x^\lambda))\\
&=0
\end{align}

...and I really don't know what's wrong...

Comment: You are dealing with the linearized theory over the Minkowski spacetime, meaning that $\Box = \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}$ (this is different from your expression as it uses the Minkowski metric in place of the metric tensor). $k^2 = 0$ then follows immediately from the wave equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute your plane wave solution into your Einstein equation, which gives

$$H_{ab} \Box e^{ik^{\mu}x_{\mu}}=H_{ab}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\beta}e^{ik^{\mu}x_{\mu}}=H_{ab}g^{\alpha\beta}ik_{\mu}\partial_{\alpha}e^{ik^{v}x_v}(\partial_{\beta}x^{\mu}).$$

Note $\partial_{\beta}x^{\mu}=\delta^{\mu}_{\beta}$.So the above becomes, after taking care of the other derivative similarly,

$$H_{ab}g^{\alpha\beta}(ik_{\alpha})(ik_{\beta})e^{ik^vx_v}=-H_{ab}e^{ik^{\mu}x_{\mu}}(k^{\nu}k_{\nu})=0$$

Thus we conclude $k^{\nu}k_{\nu}=0$.